How could I fix the InspectPlayerFromHumanoid issue? Roblox Studio
I currently have 2 local scripts inside of StarterCharacterScripts, One of them puts the proximityprompt inside the UpperTorso, the other one inspects when the proximityprompt is triggered (Right now I have it set to ended for testing purposes) This works fine, but when I try to inspect another persons avatar so I hold their proximity inside their torso down it does not inspect theirs at all. But it works completely fine when I inspect my own but when someone else tries to inspect mine it does not work either meaning its only able to inspect the local persons and no one elses why is this? (Both local scripts are inside ProximityPrompt, and the proximity is inside SCS)
It's described abov all works fine besides the fact that I can't inspect other peoples avatars.
e, it

Could you share the code you have?

The InspectPlayerFromHumanoid method is no longer used.

LocalScripts execute on each individual client, and objects created in LocalScripts are not replicated to other players.
This means that Player A will have a ProximityPrompt in their torso that they can see, and Player B will have a ProximityPrompt in their torso that they can see, but Player A will not be able to see Player B's prompt and B will not be able to see A's either.
The way to solve this is to move your logic into a Script in ServerScriptService that will create the ProximityPrompts on the server. And to keep communication simple, I would create a RemoteEvent that your LocalScripts can listen to for when the prompts are activated.
That way, every player will be able to see and interact with each other's prompts :
-- get services
local Players = game:GetService("Players")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

-- find the RemoteEvent in ReplicatedStorage
local CharacterProximityPromptActivated : RemoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage.CharacterProximityPromptActivated

-- when a player joins the game, create the proximity prompt in the player's torso
Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)
    player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(character)
        -- check if they have an R6 or R15 character model
        local torso = character.Torso
        if not torso then
            torso = character.UpperTorso
        end
        local prompt : ProximityPrompt = Instance.new("ProximityPrompt", torso)
        prompt.Triggered:Connect(function(activator)
            -- tell the player that activated the prompt to do something...
            CharacterProximityPromptActivated:FireClient(activator, player)
        end)
    end)
end)

Then, in your LocalScript, listen for when the RemoteEvent tells you that you've activated a ProximityPrompt :
local GuiService = game:GetService("GuiService")
local ReplicatedStorage = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage")

-- find the RemoteEvent in ReplicatedStorage
local CharacterProximityPromptActivated : RemoteEvent = ReplicatedStorage.CharacterProximityPromptActivated

CharacterProximityPromptActivated.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(otherPlayer : Player)
    print(string.format("You have activated %s's ProximityPrompt", otherPlayer.Name))

    -- inspect the player
    local humanoid = player.Character.Humanoid
    local humanoidDescription = humanoid:GetAppliedDescription()
    GuiService:InspectPlayerFromHumanoidDescription(humanoidDescription, otherPlayer.Name)
end)

